# How can I get my lost Vokun mask back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had the Vokun mask. I've even been back to make certain I didn't leave it on the mob etc, but now I can't find it. I can't remember if I sold it or just dumped it.

I have all the other masks and wish to use them all to get the final one.

I am entering the correct console command to get the item back, but it doesn't work.

`additem 00061cc9 1`
(I hope this is the id for the Vokun mask)

Does anyone have any ideas how to get it back?

Comment: @Terry Have you tried following the steps in OrigamiRobot's link?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code you listed is off by 1 extra digit.
Vokun mask Base ID - `00061CC9` 
you seem to have added a 1 to the end of yours.
I'm also including the codes for the rest just in case
you run into future problems : )

- Vokun mask Base ID - `00061CC9`
- Hevnoraak mask Base ID - `00061CC1`
- Krosis mask Base ID - `00061CB9`
- Morokei mask Base ID - `00061C8B`
- Nahkriin mask Base ID - `00061CA5`
- Otar mask Base ID - `00061CC2`
- Rahgot mask Base ID - `00061CC0`
- Volsung mask Base ID - `00061CAB`

I'm assuming you want to get the items to yourself, the console command for that is;

`player.additem <Base ID> <Quantity>`

Source: [Dragon Priests](http://skyrimelder.weebly.com/dragon-priest.html)

Hope this helped.

Merry X-mas!

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate. But have tried it without the 1 at the end and I get a script error. Will try it again. So my console command should read ...... additem 00061cc9  - ok fingers crossed !! Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Woot - I needed tp add the PLAYER at the start as you said. Thats what mine was missing. PLAYER.ADDITEM etc.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Merry Christmas to all you guys and gals on here :)

Comment: The 1 he added to the end is the quantity that you need to add or it won't go through.

Comment: @Terry Don't forget to mark this answer as the accepted answer if it worked for you (and also upvote it if you think it's a good answer).

Comment: The reason i told him he had added an Extra # was because of the statement in the question above...

" I am entering the correct console command to get the item back, but it doesn't work.

additem 00061cc9 1
 (I hope this is the id for the Vokun mask) "
he says he hoped this was the ID for the mask,it was in fact the ID PLUS the Qauntity, so I clarafied this to him

Comment: fyi you don't need to add the extra 0's in the front of an item code