# How can I retrieve an item that was on a follower who died?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I married Lydia and gave her the [Vokun Mask](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vokun_Mask) to hold, but later she died. I don't remember where she died and now I need the [mask](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Masks) to complete the [quest to restore the Dragon Priest Shrine](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Priest_Shrine) - do any of you know a way to find Lydia or the mask?

Comment: Duplicates: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43807/how-can-i-get-my-lost-vokun-mask-back and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38716/i-lost-my-follower

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find my follower if and when they leave me?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35296/4797) and/or [How can I find a lost item?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37365/4797)

Answer (score 3):

If you have Skyrim on the PC, you can spawn it in using console cheats. Enter this into the console, and it should spawn in front of you:

```
player.placeatme 00061cc9 1
```

You can use the (~) tilde to open the console (Hint: it's under the escape key).

---

If you have it on the Xbox (sorry if I'm wrong here, because I do not have it on the Xbox), you're in a little trouble. IIRC there's no way to spawn items on the Xbox. And I don't think there's a "find Lydia's dead body" option either.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure she is dead, try searching at Whiterun's Hall of the Dead. Enter the hall, and go  straight, enter the door, you might find some skeletons attacking you. Her body could be in one of the "coffins."(Like when Draugr wake up on their caves)

Sometimes a courier might give you some gold when Lydia dies if she was your follower for a long time. You can also try to force a bug, that when you marry someone, in the wedding, Lydia's dead body will appear and the Wedding will fail, but you can re-make the wedding saying sorry to your wife/husband.